# ImportError: cannot import name 'notf' from 'tensorboard.compat'

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, stylegan

**i am training stylegan2-ada-pytorch from google colab with my custom images however on trying to perform the initial training i get the above error from tensorboard**

```
cmd = f"/usr/bin/python3 /content/stylegan2-ada-pytorch/train.py --snap {SNAP} --outdir {EXPERIMENTS} --data {DATA}"
```

!{cmd}

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling `TensorFlow`.
I used `pip3 install tensorflow==2.9.1` and it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by uninstalling jax and reinstalling the cuda version of iy

```
!pip uninstall jax jaxlib -y
!pip install "jax[cuda11_cudnn805]==0.3.10" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
```

And then changed the torch version to 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to a compatibility issue between the Tensorboard and Numpy version, updating Numpy to the latest version could solve this issue

```
>> pip install --upgrade numpy
```